# php switch not functioning as intended

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am attempting to use the switch function of PHP but I must be doing something wrong. The code below will echo the result of the $find_top_type in the console but doesnt seem to go any further. I know the query is good having tested that and verified it through the ECHO. It doesnt seem to go further into the PHP however. It does not show me either of the other ECHO requests.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$find_top_type = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT column_1 FROM mytable WHERE id = $tid"));
echo $find_top_type;
$find_top_type = 2;
$find_top_type = 4;
$find_top_type = 6;
$find_top_type = 8;

    switch($find_top_type){
        case 2:
            echo "retuning two test";
                break;
        case "4":
            echo "retuning four test";
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the 4 assignment statements before the switch?

Comment: You don't get any output because you hardcoded `find_top_type =8` at the end and there's no case for 8. Try to learn basic concepts first. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @musa they are defining the swtiches no? Those are the conditions

Comment: The = X are what it is looking for if I have understood right?

Comment: no, you’re assigning values with the equals sign.

Comment: @ tim morton. I think I misunderstood something else then. I am trying to state that when the result is 4 from the query for $find_top_type that it uses that case. The answer to the $find_top_type is 4 so it should be using the case statement for case 4 no?

Comment: your switch/case statement is fine. case is the comparison. but your switch was always seeing 8.

Comment: What would the change be so that when $find_top_type gets an 8 from teh query it follows that, or when it gets a 4 then it uses that? Seems I have defined this incorrectly?

Comment: @Mikey no, you are assigning values to/overwriting `$find_top_type`. Do you want to do cases for when `$find_top_type` is 6 or 8 as well?

Comment: @musa yes I am looking to have the values for them all

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add default statement and end of switch case and your case 4 have not break statement.